# Where did the routing table on my Windows PC come from?

Tags: routing, ip-address

When I connect to a LAN, I know a DCHP server will provide my PC's IP address and the default gateway (these will be part of the route table) and that loopback addresses are probably automatically configured by Windows, but how are the IP addresses of the rest of the LAN added to my routing table?

Similarly, if I have 4 computers connected to a switch (disconnected form the internet), in order to communicate I need the IP addresses of the other PCs, but how do I get them? How do I know about the other PCs at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get "free" routes simply based on the IP address and subnet mask assigned to your network interfaces.

If a network interface has the IP 192.168.2.10 with subnet mask 255.255.255.0 (aka /24), then just by virtue of that assignment, the system knows that if it wants to talk to anything with an IP from 192.168.2.1 through 192.168.2.255, it can use that network interface.  So this route appears in the routing table.  This is a *directly connected* route.

---

Subnet masks determine how much of the address is used to identify the network itself, and how much is used to identify a system on that network.  I'll explain this in a simplified form.  For each 255 in the subnet mask, that corresponding number in the IP address needs to be the same on all system in a given network.

So, 192.168.2.X with subnet 255.255.255.0, you can select any X (0-255) when assigning addresses.  The 192.168.2. part must stay the same on each system.

The "2" in 192.168.2 can be any other number 0-255 you want - it just must be the same on every system's IP.  192.168.X.X is one of the "private IP ranges."

That should be enough knowledge for you to set up a small number of systems on a switch.  Study more about subnet masks to understand further.

> Similarly, if I have 4 computers connected to a switch (disconnected form the internet), in order to communicate I need the IP addresses of the other PCs, but how do I get them?

You allocate them manually according to the rules above.  A spreadsheet tool works nicely to keep track.

One thing to keep in mind is that, if you have no internet connection, you have no default gateway, and do not specify one.  You also will not be able to access any public DNS servers.

> How do I know about the other PCs at all?

Hopefully you have physically verified their presence since you are manually assigning IPs on them.  Another column on your spreadsheet to keep track. If you expect systems you don't know to be joining and leaving your network (in the case of wireless, for example), or wanting to do this without user intervention, manual IP address assignment breaks down.  Though you could always implement [Peg DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peg_DHCP).  Anyway, this is one of the reasons why DHCP was invented.

As far as systems discovering other systems, this can be done through protocols that use "broadcast" (or multicast).  The last IP in a subnet is a broadcast address.  Traffic sent here is received by any system on that subnet.  Windows uses broadcast packets to discover and resolve hosts without a DNS or WINS server running.  Multicasting is a bit different, and is used by Bonjour (iTunes, Apple devices, some printers).  So if you connect a number of Windows systems to a switch with no internet, and manually assign IPs, you can usually address them with '\hostname' without an issue because of this.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're missing a conceptual point. In order for you to want to communicate with another PC, you would have to know something about that PC. Whatever that something is, if it's convertible to an IP address, then communication is possible. So the question is -- what is that something?

Say you want to call your father on the phone. You have something, that the person you want to speak to is your father, that is connected to your desire to call him. You can't want to call a random person or do a random thing. So long as you have a way to go from knowing that the person is your father to knowing the phone number to call, you can call your father when you want to. So to answer the question "how does my computer know the IP address I want to reach", you must first answer the question, "how do I know which computer I want to reach".

For example, if you know the computer's name, there are ways to convert a name to an IP address.

Answer (score 0):

> When I connect to a LAN, … how are the IP addresses of the rest of the LAN added to my routing table?

They aren’t. When you use an IP address directly, you don’t need a routing table. You simply send a packet to the appropriate address and the router routes it to the appropriate port (hence its name).

> Similarly, if I have 4 computers connected to a switch (disconnected form the internet), in order to communicate I need the IP addresses of the other PCs, but how do I get them?

It depends on your LAN and the systems on it.

> How do I know about the other PCs at all?

By default, you don’t. You can scan for them or you can manually add them to your `HOSTS` file, but there’s no reason that you should know of them *automatically*. That’s like asking how you can know about all the computers on the Internet. You don’t know about them until you actually need to contact one, then you find out its IP address from the DNS server.

You can live and work happily without ever having anything to do with the other systems on the LAN.

Answer (score 0):

As part of provisioning networking for your system the DHCP server hands out 4 pieces of information - the DNS Servers (for converting domains to IP addresses as you probably know), the IP address, netmask and gateway.

The key to understanding this is the netmask.  The netmask defines what devices are on the LAN (ie directly connected).  Any devices not in the range defined by the netmask [ and without special routes defined ] are pushed out the default gateway - it is noteworthy that the default gateway is (should always be) a directly connected device.

To show you an example:  Your DHCP server gives you an IP address 192.168.1.10, netmask 255.255.255.0 and gateway 192.168.1.254

This means that 192.168.1.0 - 192.168.1.254 are all considered to be IP addresses directly connected to this machine.  Anything which is not known is directed out 192.168.1.254.

When the computer wants to talk to a machine which is directly connected it sends out (in IPV4, IPV6 is similar) an ARP request to all machines directly connected saying "Do you have the IP address I want to talk to".  The correct machine then replies with its Network Interface address and communication begins.   [ The process of asking all connected machines is done through a broadcast query - the last address in the network, in case of our example 192.168.1.255, and all machines listen for it ]